# net_adm:ping from one container to another

Tags: docker, erlang, docker-compose

Playing with Erlang and Docker containers.  I created a toy app across two containers: client and server.  Here's the docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '2'
services:
    client:
        image: test3_client
        links:
            - server
    server:
        image: test3_server
```

Here's the server's Dockerfile

```
FROM erlang:19.0
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app
CMD erl -sname server -setcookie abc -noshell -s test3 start
```

(the client is much the same, only with the name `client` and coming in to the `client` function of test3).  Here's the Erlang code:

```
-module (test3).

-compile(export_all).

start() ->
    register(greeter, spawn(fun() -> loop() end)) .

loop() ->
    io:format("server loop~n"),
    receive
        {greeting, Sender, Name} ->
            io:format("greeting: ~w~n", [Name]),
            Sender ! {response, self(), "Yowser " + Name}
    end,
    loop() .

client() ->
    timer:sleep(250),
    ok = ping_server(10),
    greeter ! {greeting, self, "diego"},
    receive
        {response, Pid, Greeting} ->
            io:format("I was greeted: " + Greeting + "!~n")
    end .

ping_server(Count) ->

    case Count of
        X when X < 1 ->
            {error, "unable to reach server"};
        _ ->
            case net_adm:ping(server) of
                pong ->
                    io:format("found server~n"),
                    ok ;
                pang ->
                    io:format("unable to reach server~n"),
                    timer:sleep(1000),
                    ping_server(Count - 1)
            end
    end .
```

When I run the containers, with `docker-compose up`, I get this:

```
docker-compose up
Creating network "test3_default" with the default driver
Creating test3_server_1
Creating test3_client_1
Attaching to test3_server_1, test3_client_1
server_1  | server loop
client_1  | unable to reach server
client_1  | unable to reach server
client_1  | unable to reach server
client_1  | unable to reach server
client_1  | unable to reach server
. . .
```

Eventually the client gets bored and gives up.

Can you see where I'm going wrong?

I've seen [this post](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2016/01/25/playing-with-docker-compose-and-erlang.html) by Chris Smith, which is really good.  But Chris is using sockets, whereas I want to make use of native Erlang message passing...

Answer (score 1):

There may be multiple problems, but at least one I can spot is that you're trying to ping `server` where that is not a valid node name. When you start an Erlang node, it gets a name of the form `<name>@<host>`, where host is the hostname of the machine it's running on. I'm not sure how that works with containers. You can try running `node()` on your server to see what the whole node name is, and change your `net_adm:ping()` to point to that.

Comment: I tried it both ways - I used "server@localhost" which, since both containers were on the same host, ought to have worked...

Comment: I changed the erlang vm startup param to use `erl -name server@servernode` and changed the ping accordingly, and the result was still a `pang`, even though when I printed out the node name of the server it was the same.

Comment: If you run `epmd -names` on your host machine while the dockers are running, does it show the docker Erlang nodes?